# Toggle background color with transitions on a click

Tags: html, css

This seems like something that should be pretty easy, but I really can't find a way to do it.

[animation http://doir.ir/css.gif](http://doir.ir/css.gif)

I need to change & transition the background color of a page when you click on these respective links. The closest thing I've seen that triggers this type of transition is this:

[changing body background color using only html5 and css3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15179968/changing-body-background-color-using-only-html5-and-css3)
with a [demo](http://codepen.io/thebabydino/pen/vmfyw)

which is extremely close, but this only works when the mouse is hovered over the link. I've tried replacing the pseudo selector of :hover to everything imaginable, but nothing 'sticks' after you click a link.

Basically, I have a list of  links, and when you click on any link, it plays a different song (via html5 ). I want the background to transition-change depending on the song that is currently playing. I can use javascript or jquery if its necessary. Any advice?

Comment: Click events can only be handled with Javascript. You can add a class with javascript and removing one, to gain the effect you want.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hows this? http://jsfiddle.net/u6PPn/2/

The key part is the jQuery:

```
$(".color").click(function() {
    var color = $(this).text();
    $("body").animate({ backgroundColor:color},1000);
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="color">Red</div>
<div class="color">Green</div>
<div class="color">Blue</div>
```

This way you can set `n` colors.

Comment: This is a good answer but I would recommend making the jQuery a little more simplified and universal! Good Job!

Comment: Yeah I noticed that after, Josh. No fear! Lasagna fixed it for us!

Comment: Very nice! Well there is your perfect answer mate! Mine answer smashed into a better answer, what a wonderful life ha!

Comment: Your jsfiddle link has a ';' instead of a ',' in the CSS. `(padding;0px;)`

Comment: Woopsies, oh well. The CSS is pointless in this example anyways, just a force of habit I suppose.

Answer (score 7):

I have a very diverse solution for you!

BTW: Thanks for the great challenge :p

```
<button value="black" class="black btn">Black</button>
<button value="red" class="red btn">Red</button>
<button value="brown" class="brown btn">Brown</button>
<button value="orange" class="orange btn">Orange</button>
<button value="mediumSeaGreen" class="green btn">MediumSeaGreen</button>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
  -webkit-transition: .6s ease;
  -moz-transition: .6s ease;
  -ms-transition: .6s ease;
  -o-transition: .6s ease;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.btn').on('click', function() {
   var valColor = $(this).val();

   $('body').css({
       background: valColor        
   });
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Josh_Powell/6X6Yr/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Pure **Javascript** solution for changing color (with transition effect) on button click :

```js
function changecolor(){

var x = document.getElementsByClassName("initialstate");

x[0].className="finalstate";



}
```

```css
.initialstate{

  background: red;
  
  padding: 10px;
  
  
  
}

.finalstate {
 background: cyan;
 transition: background-color 2s ease;
 
 padding: 10px; 


}
```

```html
<div class="initialstate">Hello </div>

<button onclick='changecolor()'>Click to change color </button>
```